# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError - IBM Websphere - Normal java Heap

Tags: java, websphere

Our application runs on IBM Websphere 8.5.5 on Linux 3.10.0. The Java version is JRE 1.8.0 (SR6 FP15) 32 bit. For the past 1 month we are getting frequent OutOfMemory Exceptions. The java Heap seems to be totally fine, but the java cores point towards an occupied JIT Code Cache. It looks like the IBM Classloader is unable to allocate enough memory to load the classes. (Exception trace  below)

On the application level, we have enabled JAXB schema validation for the Inbound Requests. Other than this there are no significant changes. Could this be the reason for the failure?.

How is it possible to figure out from the java Core if this really is the cause of the full JIT Code Cache?. I have used the ica107.jar from IBM to stay the Classloader analyis, but unable to figure out the memory usage of the classloader.

```
"Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError  
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) 
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:241) 
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:171) 
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:142) 
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ZipFileHandle.open(ZipFileHandle.java:42) 
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.SinglePathClassProvider.openZipFile(SinglePathClassProvider.java:219) 
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.SinglePathClassProvider.openZipFile(SinglePathClassProvider.java:228) 
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.SinglePathClassProvider.access$200(SinglePathClassProvider.java:71) 
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.SinglePathClassProvider$2.run(SinglePathClassProvider.java:377)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.SinglePathClassProvider.getClassBytesFromJar(SinglePathClassProvider.java:369)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.SinglePathClassProvider.getClassBytes(SinglePathClassProvider.java:306)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:720)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:589)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:872)
at org.exolab.castor.xml.util.ClassDescriptorResolverImpl.loadClass(ClassDescriptorResolverImpl.java:657)
```

Any pointers on where else to look would be highly appreciated.

Also attaching the java core dump

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that whatever code throws the OOM does not necessarily have to be part that eats your memory but it could just be the last straw that breaks the camel's neck. You'd need to acquire a heap dump and analyze it to find what's using all the memory.

Comment: The stack seems like a bit of an odd fit for the JIT cache, since it's not doing anything I'd obviously expect JIT for. Does the javacore have any additional explanation of the OOM? Sometimes in the trigger at the top of the javacore, it's got some additional explanation along with the error type (like "java heap space" if you exhaust the heap). Just based on the stack there, my immediate suspicion would be that you ran out of file handles, and you might want to check that your ulimits are sufficient, particularly nofiles.

Comment: @Thomas....To be more clear I have also attached the java Core dump analyis using the IBM Java core analyzer. If you have a look the java Heap seems to be fine

Comment: @Jarid...I have attached the snapshot of the Java Core Dump...Dump Event is "vmstop". Would ulimit -a get the unlimits details?

Comment: If you open the javacore in a text editor, the ulimits will show up in the 1CIUSERLIMITS section. The fact that it's "vmstop" is interesting - you typically would get a javacore on the OutOfMemoryError event as well, and one taken later when the JVM stops might not be as specifically accurate as to the root cause.

Comment: RLIMIT_MEMLOCK  -> Soft Limit - 128849018880 Hard Limit - 128849018880
RLIMIT_NOFILE  -> Soft Limit - 8192 Hard Limit - 8192
 RLIMIT_NPROC- > Soft Limit - 16384  Hard Limit - 16384.....Other than these, the rest are unlimited. I will check with the operation guys if any other java core was generated.

Comment: @Jarid...One more observation that we had is that during the period of the OOM Exception, we have this continuos wsjar:file in the SysOut.log. (Attached a screenshot above ). Not clear what is thew reason for this. Could be also be somehow related  to the OOM

Comment: The "wsjar" lines are not WAS logging - presumably that's coming from your app. wsjar is the URL protocol used by the WAS application class loaders, and it typically indicates URLs returned from getResource() calls.